# Assigning identifiable unique IDs to rows when importing data from XML

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm designing a database in which I'll be importing a large amount of data from XML daily to create or update existing rows.
Item data spans dozens of tables all related to the `item_id` in the main `item` table

For every item in the XML file, I need to check if it already exists in the database and update or create if it's not there.

Every XML belongs to a `source_id` and every item in the XML contains a unique alphanumeric ID up to 50 chars (but those IDs are not unique across all XMLs), so `source_id:xml_item_id` would be unique here

What I need is a way of finding if the item already exists in the database. Ideally, I will search by pk and use the same pk to join other tables

- <s>**Attempt 1**</s>

I've tried encoding `source_id:xml_item_id` into a `bigint` for the `pk` as well as decode the `bigint` back to the original `source_id:xml_item_id`, but most of the times this is overflowing

- So this is not going to work
- **Attempt 2**

Use a `UUID` for the `pk` and `source_id:xml_item_id` as `unique_id (string)` for which to search by, but join related tables to `UUID`

- While I don't see anything wrong here (IMO), `JOINs` might be affected, and I would prefer numeric `pk` for use in `URLs`
- **Attempt 3**

Use `source_id:xml_item_id` as `pk (string)`

- Same worries as with **Attempt 2**

The reason I've avoided `AI PKs` in all attempts is that there is a high possibility to shard this data in the future and I'd like this to have a relatively low impact on how `PKs` are being generated when this happens

What would be the best approach to handle this?

- To identify if items already exist in the database
- Have a user-friendly pk for URLs
- Try not to impact JOIN performance too much

Answer (score 0):

You can use unique together

```
class Data(models.Model):
    source_id = models.CharField()
    xml_item_id = models.CharField()
    # ... other fields

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("source_id", "xml_item_id")
```

Then in your import function just:

```
scid = your_xml_source_id
xmlid = your_xml_id
obj, created = Data.objects.get_or_create(source_id=scid, xml_item_id=xmlid)
if created:
    # it's the new object, populate obj with the rest of the data
    obj.other_field = your_xml_other_field
else:
    # it's existing object, update object with a new value
    obj.other_field = new_value
obj.save()
```